# How can multiply two dual quaternions for finite motion composition?

Tags: math, vector, quaternions, robotics

I'm currently digging in 'Finite and Instantaneous Screw Theory in Robotic Mechanism' by T. Sun, there are some mathematical equations which I couldn't understand. (Seems it's simple vector problem)

The problem is, when two dual quaternion D_a, D_b is exist,
which D_a = D_sa + D_va where D_sa means scalar of D_a, and D_va is vector of D_a

When multiply D_b and D_a (D_b D_a), does answer become

D_b D_a = D_sa D_sb + D_sb D_va + D_sa D_vb + D_vb X D_va - D_va (dot) D_vb  ?

I can understand until D_sa D_sb + D_sb D_va + D_sa D_vb, but not D_vb X D_va - D_va (dot) D_vb

((dot) means dot product, and X means cross product)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Oh, I just got the answer.
it was because of nature of quaternion

(a + bi + cj + dk) * (w + xi + yj + zk) = aw -(bx + cy + dz) + ( ....